# listwiew items show popup when mouse is over that item in mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

i have a listbox with many items.when i put mouse on the items it should show the items name like a popup or something .how it is possible

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `title` attribute:

```
<ul>
    <li title="item 1">item 1</li>
    <li title="item 2">item 2</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

And for nicer looking tooltips you may checkout the [qTip jquery plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).

Comment: i dont want like this.i am getting the id only from the listbox.use that id i can get the text of the id also.i want to tooltip the text when mouse is over the listbox.